# ruby server stability on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, thin

My RoR app on windows (xp as well as server 2008) stops responding after maybe a couple of days.
Using guidance from stackoverflow as well, I set up services to run the server automatically at startup. I tried different products: webrick, mongrel with mongrel_service, thin – both standalone or with an apache proxy. They start ok and work fine, but after a certain amount of time (rather than load) it stops responding.
I don't see anything in the logs either, even if I have the server run from the command line I don't get any error messages there nor does the process end, the server just does not answer anymore. Has anybody else come across this?

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

There are so many issues with windows that our whole company switched to ubuntu. I would not advise this as a production solution.